# geoIpEnrich Processor NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to utilize the geoEnrichIP processor as part of a nifi flow.  I'm trying to follow the documentation https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-enrich-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.GeoEnrichIP/ without luck.

I'm trying to attach the geoEnrichIP processor at the end of a convertRecord Processor.

ConvertRecord(Json) ---> geoEnrichIP

in the configuration for the geoEnrichIP I've added an attribute for the ip address field.  The Field is `Enrich: host_address`  But I'm not getting anything in my output.  I don't think I'm referencing the field `host_address` which contains the IP Address.

How do you properly reference the ip address name of `host_address` to enrich with geolocation data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [GeoEnrichIP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-enrich-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.GeoEnrichIP/) the field you want to enrich on must be an Attribute of the FlowFile, not part of the FlowFile content (e.g. inside a record).

The `IP Address Attribute` property must contain the name of the Attribute.

If the IP is in the FlowFile content, you'll need to extract the IP and put the value in an Attribute.

There are a few ways to do this, depending on your use case - but there's also an alternative approach.

1. If every FlowFile contains only a SINGLE Record, then you can use
   `EvaluateJsonPath` to extract the IP and create an Attribute.
2. If every FlowFile contains MULTIPLE Records, with completely random IP addresses, you could use `SplitJson` to create unique FlowFiles and then `EvaluateJsonPath` (this is usually a pattern to avoid!)
3. If every FlowFile contains MULTIPLE Records, but the IP is one of a smaller set of common IP addresses, then you could use `PartitionRecord` to bucket Records into FlowFiles with a common IP Attribute.

**However**, rather than using `GeoEnrichIP`, you could instead use [LookupRecord](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/) with an [IPLookupService](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.lookup.maxmind.IPLookupService/index.html). In this way, you can handle either SINGLE or MULTIPLE Records per FlowFile and you do not need to deal with Attributes, instead relying on data within the Record itself. This handles all 3 cases listed above.

I wrote a post about using LookupRecord [here](https://alasdairb.com/2021/05/16/enriching-records-with-lookuprecord-rest-apis-in-nifi/) if you need more details on how to use it, it's a very powerful processor for enrichment workflows.

Comment: Hello @Sdairs thanks for the informative post.  I checked out your blog post as well and was very helpful.  I'm a little stuck on the iplookup service portion.

I have a convert record processor with a json output.  I have successfully verified the key/value `host_address:111.111.111.111` exists in the queue.  I have the `LookupRecord` Processor connected.  

Record Reader: JsonTree
Record Writer: JsonWriter
lookup service: configured and point to path of maxmind file. However I get 'user-defined' properties error.  What else needs to be done to connect `host_address` to lookup?

Comment: Take a look at the doc page for LookupRecord - specifically the Dynamic Properties. You must add a dynamic property that contains a record path to the field in the Record that you want to perform the lookup on. In this case the value of your dynamic property would be `/host_address`

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I didn't pay enough attention to the Dynamic Properties settings and got this figured out.  Thanks again.