# How to resolve ip coordinates error message when using the lookuprecord + iplookupservice processor?

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I'm referencing this Stack Overflow article for enriching the IP address with geolocation information: [geoIpEnrich Processor NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290087/geoipenrich-processor-nifi)

Per the `IPLookupService` docs the property key is set to `ip` and targeting the `/host_ip` field.  I set the `Ressult RecordPath` to `/enrichment`

The processor fails every time with an error message along the lines of:

`Failed to lookup coordinates {ip=111.xxx.xxx.xxx} in Lookup Service`  and just continues with that error for every IP that it attempts to lookup.

Can anyone provide any troubleshooting steps?  I don't even care about coordinates, just the city information if that helps.